# PHP loop including some javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop, highcharts

I have a javascript function (I've took it from highcharts examples) that goes like this:

```
$(function () {    


(...)

series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Alabama',
            y: 1010,
            drilldown: 'Alabama counties'
        }, {
            name: 'Alaska',
            y: 77,
            drilldown: 'Alaska counties'
        }, {
            name: 'Arizona',
            y: 947,
            drilldown: 'Arizona counties'
        }]
```

This accepts only Alabama, Alaska and Arizona (I'm trying to make a plot with fatalities per state).

I've succefully connected my postgres database to a php script and I have two arrays:

```
$state_name  and $fatalities
```

I would like to do some kind of lop (for or foreach) that can fetch the state name and number of fatalities to automatically generate more states, in the series... Otherwise I have to make it one by one!

I've tried lots of different ways but my code is a mess, I can tell where php ends and javaScript begins anymore... Can you give me some help?

So, I've tried to generate only name and y, and currently this is what I had in mind...

```
<?php


// Connection parameters
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "postgres"; 
$pass = "iniciativa2"; 
$db = "crash15042014";


// Connecting...
$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
or die ("Could not connect to server\n");


$query = "select state_id, state_name, sum(noofcrashes) as total
from locationdim locdim, eventfacts ev
where locdim.location_id = ev.location_id
group by locdim.state_id, locdim.state_name
order by locdim.state_id;
";

$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");


$state_name = array();
$deaths = array();



while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
array_push($state_name, $row['state_name']);
array_push($deaths, $row['total']);
}

print_r($state_name);
echo "<br>";
print_r($deaths);

//This is fine      


pg_close($con); 


// From here, I have no clue...
for ($i = 0; $i <= 56; $i++) { ?>

            name: <?php "'". echo $state_name[$i] . "'"; ?>,
            y: <?php echo $deaths[$i]; ?>,
            drilldown: <?php "'". echo $state_name[$i] . "counties'"; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using json_encode / json_decode?

Comment: can you share the code even if its messy

Comment: I've edited for you to see... I've also tried creating an array in a foreach loop with $array = array('name:'=>$state_name[$i], 'y:' =>$deaths[$i] and then json_encode($array) but I am not really sure what I am doing... This is new for me...

Comment: Share the code even if it's messy. otherwise, just think about using json_encode() and json_decode() functions, they're gonna make your life easier

Comment: You can have one array and add values to it in query loop like so:  
$state_name = $row['state_name'];
$result_array["$state_name"]['state'] = $state_name;   
$result_array["$state_name"]['deaths'][] = $row['deaths'];
Then at least you have one array with state => death total pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating your entire `data` array for the javascript in PHP.  E.g.

```
$death_data = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
   $death_data[] = array(
      'name' => $row['state_name'],
      'y' => $row['total'],
      'drilldown' => $row['state_name'] + ' counties', //Work out what you want here
   );
}
```

Then pass that to the javascript via JSON format and create a javascript array which you can use for your series.  Example (the question is not tagged jQuery but you appear from your example to be using jQuery so I have used it.  If you are not using jQuery you must find an alternative to `$.parseJSON` but the rest holds):

$(function () {

```
(...)

var death_data = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($death_data); ?>');

series: [{
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true
    data: death_data
```

Comment: What the heck is `$.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($death_data); ?>');`

Comment: Just do `var death_data = <?php echo json_encode($death_data); ?>`

Comment: THe php echos a string in JSON format.  `$.parseJSON` takes that string (which it sees as a static string since the PHP wrote it out there) and parses it to recreate an array/object in javascript.  `$.parseJSON` is a jQuery function but there are options in vanilla js as well.

Comment: I'm not new to this. You're serializing and immediately unserializing. Just echo the JSON directly. The JS in JSON means Javascript. You can echo it directly into javascript.

Comment: Yes, you can.  But making it a string and parsing it back up is, in my opinion, safer.  Echoing it directly in is equivalent to using eval instead of JSON, in my opinion.  But yes, both work.  The situations where it is an issue are edge cases - it's my habbit to go via parseJSON.  The guts of the answer are the same whether you echo it or use parseJSON

Comment: Could you point me to an edge case where `json_encode($anything)` will evaluate arbitrary code?

Comment: json_encode() should be places in php script, then in javascript you need to use $.getJSON() function;

Comment: @Joe Frambach: I read an article a cpouple of years ago which pointed out some potential problems using eval() (instead of a proper JSON parser) to evaluate JSON-encoded strings to objects.  I can't remember the details but when I got your first question I reasoned that "direct evaluation is the same as eval()". I suspect that the problems probably came from misformed JSON and that given you are directly outputting the contents of `json_encode()` it is not an issue here. As I said in my 1nd comment, it's become habbit to always go via `$.parseJSON()` but may well be unecesary here. Both work:)

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan: NO - `$.getJSON()` runs an ajax-request to the server to fetch the JSON data.  Here we have the data already when we render the page and simply wish to create a javascript array based on the PHP array.  So we can either echo it directly as @Joe Frambach points out or use `$.parseJSON()` as in my answer.